# How to cancel all Toasts when app is in background?

Tags: android, android-toast

I'm using `Toasts` in my app to display errors from API/local errors to user. But it is annoying if user is in background and `Toast` message is displayed over his Messenger app (for example) that some request failed. Is there any way how to disable all displayed toasts immediately when App is in background?

All toasts are created in one function for entire App which is inside my `Application` class.

Comment: Why don't you use `lifeCycle` and check whether your app is in background if any activity is in background then don't display toast ? Does this make sense ? Leran more about [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a variable in your MasterActivity (if you have one, or set in your MainActivity) like this:

```
  public static boolean IS_IN_FOREGROUND = false;
```

and set it in your lifecycle like this:

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IS_IN_FOREGROUND = true;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    IS_IN_FOREGROUND = false;
  }
```

then check it before calling your toast method.